# How to Auto Generate of Guid ID in .NET CORE 6?

Tags: .net-6.0, guid

In my request data, if I have a duplication Guid ID, I want to generate a new Guid ID automatically. How to do it?

`public class Roster { public Guid Id {get; set;} }`

Here `Guid Id` is the primary key.

When I made an api post request, what would be the value I give for Guid Id?

Comment: In my api post request, what would I give the value for Guid Id?

Comment: When you set `Guid` as `pk` and insert data into db, You don't need to set the value of `Guid` manually, The database will automatically generate data for `Guid` without duplication

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL and EntityFramework Core you could use this inside your model:

```cs
 [Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
```

This will tell EF:

- this property is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table hence the `[KEY]`
- this property should be automatically generated by the database

**FYI** you need to set a `DEFAULT` value for you SQL column like so: [image: DEFAULT]

- `(newsequentiaid())` tells SQL that he's in charge of creating a Globally Unique Id everytime you add a record to that table

Don't know if this is the answer you were looking for (nex time provide more info for us) anyway
hope this helps you Cheers!

### UPDATE

I do not know if my solution works with MySQL i use it for SQL. Searching a bit online i found no resources to `newsequentialid` in MySQL database (but i could be wrong, do your own research if you'd like).

Anyway i just don't set it for example:

```cs
 var activityDB = await context.Activity.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ActivityId == activity.ActivityId);
  if (activityDB == null)
  {
     activityDB = new Activity();
     context.Activity.Add(activityDB);
  }
     activityDB.Code = activity.Code;
     activityDB.Description = activity.Description;
     activityDB.Status = activity.Status;
```

**Here's what the code does**

- check if my id exists if yes i have to edit if is null i don't
- create new activity and edit
- automatically EF nows what id to handle therefore no need to se it
- If there is it means im editing for that id if not will create it automatically

Comment: then in my post request for Guid ID what would be the value i insert? Will I keep it empty string?  

Tried your solution but didn't work. Duplicate entry error. I am using MySQL and Entity Framework core

Answer (score 0):

```
This works for me

My model
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public T Id { get; set; }

And added the below code in the Context class
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

ef: Add-migration "UniqueIdGeneration"
ef: update-database
```